# One of our DNS servers is hosted by our old host and one by the new. The old doesn't have the correct values and can't be changed

Tags: web-hosting, dns, dns-servers

Because of misbehavior of our old hoster justhost.com, our domains including victorporton.com do not act as they should.

But justhost.com ignores our queries saying that they can't help because our account with them is terminated. (They forgot to remove our DNS information, however.)

The correct IP to which the DNS must point is 176.9.146.215.

I wrote to Verisign asking to take an action against justhost, but my email was not answered. What else can be done?

Below there is a description of technical conditions:

---

Our nameservers are pointing to ns1.kleinburdhost.com and ns2.kleinburdhost.com.

When we try to resolve the domain victorporton.com the following happens:

`$ dig @a.gtld-servers.net victorporton.com 
...
ns1.kleinburdhost.com.  172800  IN  A   74.220.195.44
ns2.kleinburdhost.com.  172800  IN  A   69.89.16.124`

Note that it has returned the wrong IPs.

These IPs are from their nameserver:

`$ dig @74.220.195.44 ns1.kleinburdhost.com
...
ns1.kleinburdhost.com.  60  IN  A   74.220.199.15`

`$ dig @74.220.195.44 kleinburdhost.com
...
kleinburdhost.com.  60  IN  A   74.220.199.15`

Note that two last dig queries to your nameserver return wrong IPs.

When resolving the IP for ns1.kleinburdhost.com the nameserver 74.220.195.44 uses its parent server kleinburdhost.com (which has a wrong IP in this response) and when resolving the IP for kleinburdhost.com it uses the nameserver ns1.kleinburdhost.com or ns2.kleinburdhost.com (which also have wrong IPs in this response).

Thus it happens a vicious circle: The top level domain servers such as a.gtld-servers.net use nameservers ns1.kleinburdhost.com or ns2.kleinburdhost.com with wrong IPs to resolve kleinburdhost.com and to resolve ns1.kleinburdhost.com or ns2.kleinburdhost.com servers it uses their parent kleinburdhost.com with wrong IPs is used. This leads to the fact that both ns1.kleinburdhost.com, ns2.kleinburdhost.com, and kleinburdhost.com are queried with wrong IPs.

Comment: Can't you just delegate the domain to your new provider (through your domain registrar's control panel)? Whether or not your old host still hold DNS records is then irrelevant.

Comment: What @TimFountain says.   Change the name server (NS) records at your domain registrar to point to the name servers for your new host.  Then your old host will be completely ignored.

Comment: It also isn't clear from your question exactly who owns what.   Who owns the ns1.kleinburdhost.com dns servers?  Is that your old host, your new host, or you?

Comment: Another way to solve the problem would be to use the DNS servers of your registrar.   For example if you GoDaddy, you can use NS records for Goddady's servers and put the A record into GoDaddy's DNS server:  https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238

Comment: @StephenOstermiller There are two ns1.kleinburdhost.com servers: one which we own now and one which we owned in the past (with justhost.com) but now it is not under our control. This (last) NS server works wrongly.

Comment: We cannot "Change the name server (NS) records at your domain registrar to point to the name servers for your new host", because old (now wrong) and new nameservers have the same domain name {ns1,ns2}.kleinburdhost.com - the error is that a wrong IP is returned for the nameservers themselves (see the questions for all details)

Comment: That clears some things up.   You shouldn't ever need to own your name servers.   You should just use somebody else's name servers.     Doing so is far more reliable.  Switch the name server records from ns1.kleinburdhost.com to the values given to you by either your web host or your registrar.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Another fine example of the dangers of vanity NS. What is really bad is that too many sites give instructions to set these vanity NS DNS servers up as if that is normal business without warning of the huge dangers involved. As a former web host, I know this is a huge No! No! even when you know what you are doing and even when you own everything and have full control. For the OP, I would go back to the registrar. It sounds like the registrar was not as helpful as they can be. Try asking for a supervisor.

Comment: Depends on the registrar though.  Not all registrars offer DNS hosting.

Comment: @closetnoc Who should I ask "for a supervisor"?

Comment: When you call your registrar, ask for a supervisor. The reason is simple. They have more experience and can contact more technical personnel to help you. Since you registered the domain with them, they can uniquely take over and fix the authority for your domain. No one else can. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

`ns2.kleinburdhost.com` is a glue inside .com registry, registered by eNom with IP 176.9.146.219, same for `ns1` with IP 176.9.146.215

If this is not the IP you want you will need to go through eNom to make this value be changed at the registry. But this seems to be correct IPs now based on your question.

Note that using glues, why not super advanced DNS mastery, is still prone to errors, so this should be used carefully.

Comment: You described the problem (which we knew) not the solution. Well, anyway we have already solved the problem by communicating with the hoster.

Comment: Thanks for your very useful comment, that makes helping you very desirable. You never realised you add a glue and what that entails, at least from your question (and I am not sure you are understanding the problem even now so you may risk to encounter it again in the future), and you did never update your question here to say your problem is resolved, in order to let people stop trying to help you. Post your "solution" as an answer here and accept it to close the question, thank you in advance!